# How to really delete a document in pouchDb?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I deleted a document which had a specific id, now I would like to create a new one which has the same id. I can't create it with a different id, because I use my ids "to store object informations", by the way idk if it's good practice. For example my ids looks like this:

A document which store a project: `p0`

A document which store a worker from project 'p0': `p0/w0`

A document which store a second worker from project 'p0': `p0/w1`

etc..

So for example, instead of adding a property 'projectId' to a worker document, I use its id **to store this information**, this is what I mean by "using ids to store object informations". Then when I need workers from project 'p0', I request to pouchDb all documents ids beginning by 'p0'. Then I filter my result to get only ids matching the worker id regex ( `p[0-9]+\/w[0-9]+` ), and I perform a second request on these ids, including docs.

So I deleted by mistake my document 'p0' and I would like to create it again, how to do ? Is my method to handle my docs correct ?

Comment: Do you want to restore `p0` or create a new whole project with `p0` as key?

Comment: I would like to restore p0, if it's not possible then just create a new doc with p0 id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always recover any document revision in PouchDB, assuming you don't enable auto-compaction or call `compact()`.

Unfortunately there's no plugin to make this simple, but basically you need to `get()` the document with the options `{revs: true, open_revs: 'all'}`, and then you get an object called `_revisions` that describes the entire document history, and from that you can recover lost revisions. E.g. if the object is:

```
{_revisions: {start: 3, ids: ['x', 'y', 'z']}}
```

Then the revision ids are `'1-z'`, `'2-y'`, and `'3-x'`, which you can then fetch by `get()`ing with e.g. `{rev: '1-x'}`

There's a longer explanation here: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/11/couchdb-restoring-deletedupdated.html